# Yii - how to deal with extending CFormModel and CFormModel

Tags: inheritance, yii, gii

Let's say i have a database table called 'people'.

70% of the fields in this table are created by the user submitting a form, the other 30% are fields populated from other data.

To describe this table I used Gii to create a model (People.php) which extends CActiveRecord.

I then realisied that to display a form I need to extend CFormModel.  This class need only display to the user and collect data for 70% of the database fields.  It's only purpose is to display a form and collect data.

My question is how can this be done when I already have a model class called People?

Thank you.  Hope that makes sense,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can as well create a form using [CActiveForm](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm/) class, which can directly relate form fields to model fields.

It will be a lot easier if you generate your controller and views as well from Gii, and then you can customize it as you like.

Comment: Yeah, it seems just using CRUD generator rather than seperately creating model, controller, view is the fastest way to get up and running.  Thanks for your time